# I can not resolve this error in SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, sugarbean

In SugarCRM (program management) module called "projects" by default does not come with the "import", it added eh following programming steps:

```
http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f148/how-add-importación-opción-custom-modules-45612/
```

Now I throw the error when I Import Next:

> Fatal error: Llamada a una función miembro get_importable_fields () en un no-objeto en C: \ Archivos de programa \ Apache Software Foundation \ Apache2.2 \ htdocs \ Azúcar \ modules \ Import \ v iews \ view.step3.php en línea 217

Please somebody help me ... if necessary ... I will upload the file so they can help view.step3.php

Here is the line 217:

```
        $fields  = $this->bean->get_importable_fields();
        $options = array();
        $defaultField = '';
        global $current_language;
        $moduleStrings = return_module_language($current_language, $this->bean->module_dir);
```

Here I publish the above lines:

```
class ImportViewStep3 extends ImportView
```

{

```
protected $pageTitleKey = 'LBL_STEP_3_TITLE';
protected $currentFormID = 'importstep3';
protected $previousAction = 'Confirm';
protected $nextAction = 'dupcheck';

/**
 * @see SugarView::display()
 */
public function display()
{
    global $mod_strings, $app_strings, $current_user, $sugar_config, $app_list_strings, $locale;

    $this->ss->assign("IMPORT_MODULE", $_REQUEST['import_module']);
    $has_header = ( isset( $_REQUEST['has_header']) ? 1 : 0 );
    $sugar_config['import_max_records_per_file'] = ( empty($sugar_config['import_max_records_per_file']) ? 1000 : $sugar_config['import_max_records_per_file'] );
    $this->ss->assign("CURRENT_STEP", $this->currentStep);
    // attempt to lookup a preexisting field map
    // use the custom one if specfied to do so in step 1
    $mapping_file = new ImportMap();
    $field_map = $mapping_file->set_get_import_wizard_fields();
    $default_values = array();
    $ignored_fields = array();

    if ( !empty( $_REQUEST['source_id']))
    {
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("Loading import map properties.");
        $mapping_file = new ImportMap();
        $mapping_file->retrieve( $_REQUEST['source_id'],false);
        $_REQUEST['source'] = $mapping_file->source;
        $has_header = $mapping_file->has_header;
        if (isset($mapping_file->delimiter))
            $_REQUEST['custom_delimiter'] = $mapping_file->delimiter;
        if (isset($mapping_file->enclosure))
            $_REQUEST['custom_enclosure'] = htmlentities($mapping_file->enclosure);
        $field_map = $mapping_file->getMapping();
        //print_r($field_map);die();
        $default_values = $mapping_file->getDefaultValues();
        $this->ss->assign("MAPNAME",$mapping_file->name);
        $this->ss->assign("CHECKMAP",'checked="checked" value="on"');
    }
    else
    {
        $classname = $this->getMappingClassName(ucfirst($_REQUEST['source']));

        //Set the $_REQUEST['source'] to be 'other' for ImportMapOther special case
        if($classname == 'ImportMapOther')
        {
            $_REQUEST['source'] = 'other';
        }

        if (class_exists($classname))
        {
            $mapping_file = new $classname;
            $ignored_fields = $mapping_file->getIgnoredFields($_REQUEST['import_module']);
            $field_map2 = $mapping_file->getMapping($_REQUEST['import_module']);
            $field_map = array_merge($field_map,$field_map2);
        }
    }

    $delimiter = $this->getRequestDelimiter();

    $this->ss->assign("CUSTOM_DELIMITER", $delimiter);
    $this->ss->assign("CUSTOM_ENCLOSURE", ( !empty($_REQUEST['custom_enclosure']) ? $_REQUEST['custom_enclosure'] : "" ));

   //populate import locale  values from import mapping if available, these values will be used througout the rest of the code path

    $uploadFileName = $_REQUEST['file_name'];

    // Now parse the file and look for errors
    $importFile = new ImportFile( $uploadFileName, $delimiter, html_entity_decode($_REQUEST['custom_enclosure'],ENT_QUOTES), FALSE);

    if ( !$importFile->fileExists() ) {
        $this->_showImportError($mod_strings['LBL_CANNOT_OPEN'],$_REQUEST['import_module'],'Step2');
        return;
    }

    $charset = $importFile->autoDetectCharacterSet();

    // retrieve first 3 rows
    $rows = array();

    //Keep track of the largest row count found.
    $maxFieldCount = 0;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ )
    {
        $rows[] = $importFile->getNextRow();
        $maxFieldCount = $importFile->getFieldCount() > $maxFieldCount ?  $importFile->getFieldCount() : $maxFieldCount;
    }
    $ret_field_count = $maxFieldCount;

    // Bug 14689 - Parse the first data row to make sure it has non-empty data in it
    $isempty = true;
    if ( $rows[(int)$has_header] != false ) {
        foreach ( $rows[(int)$has_header] as $value ) {
            if ( strlen(trim($value)) > 0 ) {
                $isempty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($isempty || $rows[(int)$has_header] == false) {
        $this->_showImportError($mod_strings['LBL_NO_LINES'],$_REQUEST['import_module'],'Step2');
        return;
    }

    // save first row to send to step 4
    $this->ss->assign("FIRSTROW", base64_encode(serialize($rows[0])));

    // Now build template
    $this->ss->assign("TMP_FILE", $uploadFileName );
    $this->ss->assign("SOURCE", $_REQUEST['source'] );
    $this->ss->assign("TYPE", $_REQUEST['type'] );
    $this->ss->assign("DELETE_INLINE_PNG",  SugarThemeRegistry::current()->getImage('basic_search','align="absmiddle" alt="'.$app_strings['LNK_DELETE'].'" border="0"'));
    $this->ss->assign("PUBLISH_INLINE_PNG",  SugarThemeRegistry::current()->getImage('advanced_search','align="absmiddle" alt="'.$mod_strings['LBL_PUBLISH'].'" border="0"'));

    $this->instruction = 'LBL_SELECT_MAPPING_INSTRUCTION';
    $this->ss->assign('INSTRUCTION', $this->getInstruction());

    $this->ss->assign("MODULE_TITLE", $this->getModuleTitle(false));
    $this->ss->assign("STEP4_TITLE",
        strip_tags(str_replace("\n","",getClassicModuleTitle(
            $mod_strings['LBL_MODULE_NAME'],
            array($mod_strings['LBL_MODULE_NAME'],$mod_strings['LBL_STEP_4_TITLE']),
            false
            )))
        );
    $this->ss->assign("HEADER", $app_strings['LBL_IMPORT']." ". $mod_strings['LBL_MODULE_NAME']);

    // we export it as email_address, but import as email1
    $field_map['email_address'] = 'email1';

    // build each row; row count is determined by the the number of fields in the import file
    $columns = array();
    $mappedFields = array();

    // this should be populated if the request comes from a 'Back' button click
    $importColumns = $this->getImportColumns();
    $column_sel_from_req = false;
    if (!empty($importColumns)) {
        $column_sel_from_req = true;
    }

    for($field_count = 0; $field_count < $ret_field_count; $field_count++) {
        // See if we have any field map matches
        $defaultValue = "";
        // Bug 31260 - If the data rows have more columns than the header row, then just add a new header column
        if ( !isset($rows[0][$field_count]) )
            $rows[0][$field_count] = '';
        // See if we can match the import row to a field in the list of fields to import
        $firstrow_name = trim(str_replace(":","",$rows[0][$field_count]));
        if ($has_header && isset( $field_map[$firstrow_name] ) ) {
            $defaultValue = $field_map[$firstrow_name];
        }
        elseif (isset($field_map[$field_count])) {
            $defaultValue = $field_map[$field_count];
        }
        elseif (empty( $_REQUEST['source_id'])) {
            $defaultValue = trim($rows[0][$field_count]);
        }

        // build string of options
        $fields  = $this->bean->get_importable_fields();
```

Comment: Can you detail the changes you made to the Project SugarBean class?

Comment: The only change I made was to add in project.php:

var $importable = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my coding project.php:

class Project extends SugarBean {
    // database table columns

```
var $id;
var $date_entered;
var $date_modified;
var $assigned_user_id;
var $modified_user_id;
var $created_by;
var $name;
var $description;
var $deleted;


// related information
var $assigned_user_name;
var $modified_by_name;
var $created_by_name;

var $account_id;
var $contact_id;
var $opportunity_id;
var $email_id;
var $estimated_start_date;

// calculated information
var $total_estimated_effort;
var $total_actual_effort;

var $object_name = 'Project';
var $module_dir = 'Project';
var $new_schema = true;
var $table_name = 'project';
var $importable = true;

// This is used to retrieve related fields from form posts.
var $additional_column_fields = array(
    'account_id',
    'contact_id',
    'opportunity_id',
);

var $relationship_fields = array(
    'account_id' => 'accounts',
    'contact_id'=>'contacts',
    'opportunity_id'=>'opportunities',
    'email_id' => 'emails',
);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// METHODS
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 *
 */
function Project()
{
    parent::SugarBean();
}

/**
 * overriding the base class function to do a join with users table
 */

/**
 *
 */
function fill_in_additional_detail_fields()
{
    parent::fill_in_additional_detail_fields();

    $this->assigned_user_name = get_assigned_user_name($this->assigned_user_id);
    //$this->total_estimated_effort = $this->_get_total_estimated_effort($this->id);
    //$this->total_actual_effort = $this->_get_total_actual_effort($this->id);
}

/**
 *
 */
function fill_in_additional_list_fields()
{
    parent::fill_in_additional_list_fields();
    $this->assigned_user_name = get_assigned_user_name($this->assigned_user_id);
    //$this->total_estimated_effort = $this->_get_total_estimated_effort($this->id);
    //$this->total_actual_effort = $this->_get_total_actual_effort($this->id);
}

/**
* Save changes that have been made to a relationship.
*
* @param $is_update true if this save is an update.
*/
function save_relationship_changes($is_update, $exclude=array())
{
    parent::save_relationship_changes($is_update, $exclude);
    $new_rel_id = false;
    $new_rel_link = false;
    //this allows us to dynamically relate modules without adding it to the relationship_fields array
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['relate_id']) && !in_array($_REQUEST['relate_to'], $exclude) && $_REQUEST['relate_id'] != $this->id){
        $new_rel_id = $_REQUEST['relate_id'];
        $new_rel_relname = $_REQUEST['relate_to'];
        if(!empty($this->in_workflow) && !empty($this->not_use_rel_in_req)) {
            $new_rel_id = $this->new_rel_id;
            $new_rel_relname = $this->new_rel_relname;
        }
        $new_rel_link = $new_rel_relname;
        //Try to find the link in this bean based on the relationship
        foreach ( $this->field_defs as $key => $def ) {
            if (isset($def['type']) && $def['type'] == 'link'
            && isset($def['relationship']) && $def['relationship'] == $new_rel_relname) {
                $new_rel_link = $key;
            }
        }
        if ($new_rel_link == 'contacts') {
            $accountId = $this->db->getOne('SELECT account_id FROM accounts_contacts WHERE contact_id=' . $this->db->quoted($new_rel_id));
            if ($accountId !== false) {
                if($this->load_relationship('accounts')){
                    $this->accounts->add($accountId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
/**
 *
 */
function _get_total_estimated_effort($project_id)
{
    $return_value = '';

    $query = 'SELECT SUM('.$this->db->convert('estimated_effort', "IFNULL", 0).') total_estimated_effort';
    $query.= ' FROM project_task';
    $query.= " WHERE parent_id='{$project_id}' AND deleted=0";

    $result = $this->db->query($query,true," Error filling in additional detail fields: ");
    $row = $this->db->fetchByAssoc($result);
    if($row != null)
    {
        $return_value = $row['total_estimated_effort'];
    }

    return $return_value;
}

/**
 *
 */
function _get_total_actual_effort($project_id)
{
    $return_value = '';

    $query = 'SELECT SUM('.$this->db->convert('actual_effort', "IFNULL", 0).') total_actual_effort';
    $query.=  ' FROM project_task';
    $query.=  " WHERE parent_id='{$project_id}' AND deleted=0";

    $result = $this->db->query($query,true," Error filling in additional detail fields: ");
    $row = $this->db->fetchByAssoc($result);
    if($row != null)
    {
        $return_value = $row['total_actual_effort'];
    }

    return $return_value;
}

/**
 *
 */
function get_summary_text()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 *
 */
function build_generic_where_clause ($the_query_string)
{
    $where_clauses = array();
    $the_query_string = $GLOBALS['db']->quote($the_query_string);
    array_push($where_clauses, "project.name LIKE '%$the_query_string%'");

    $the_where = '';
    foreach($where_clauses as $clause)
    {
        if($the_where != '') $the_where .= " OR ";
        $the_where .= $clause;
    }

    return $the_where;
}

function get_list_view_data()
{
    $field_list = $this->get_list_view_array();
    $field_list['USER_NAME'] = empty($this->user_name) ? '' : $this->user_name;
    $field_list['ASSIGNED_USER_NAME'] = $this->assigned_user_name;
    return $field_list;
}
  function bean_implements($interface){
    switch($interface){
        case 'ACL':return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function create_export_query(&$order_by, &$where, $relate_link_join='')
{
    $custom_join = $this->custom_fields->getJOIN(true, true,$where);
    if($custom_join)
            $custom_join['join'] .= $relate_link_join;
    $query = "SELECT
            project.*,
            users.user_name as assigned_user_name ";
    if($custom_join){
        $query .=  $custom_join['select'];
    }
    $query .= " FROM project ";

    if($custom_join){
        $query .=  $custom_join['join'];
    }
    $query .= " LEFT JOIN users
                ON project.assigned_user_id=users.id ";

    $where_auto = " project.deleted=0 ";

    if($where != "")
        $query .= "where ($where) AND ".$where_auto;
    else
        $query .= "where ".$where_auto;

    if(!empty($order_by)){
        //check to see if order by variable already has table name by looking for dot "."
        $table_defined_already = strpos($order_by, ".");

        if($table_defined_already === false){
            //table not defined yet, define accounts to avoid "ambigous column" SQL error
            $query .= " ORDER BY $order_by";
        }else{
            //table already defined, just add it to end of query
            $query .= " ORDER BY $order_by";
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
function getAllProjectTasks(){
    $projectTasks = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM project_task WHERE project_id = '" . $this->id. "' AND deleted = 0 ORDER BY project_task_id";
    $result = $this->db->query($query,true,"Error retrieving project tasks");
    $row = $this->db->fetchByAssoc($result);

    while ($row != null){
        $projectTaskBean = new ProjectTask();
        $projectTaskBean->id = $row['id'];
        $projectTaskBean->retrieve();
        array_push($projectTasks, $projectTaskBean);

        $row = $this->db->fetchByAssoc($result);
    }

    return $projectTasks;
}
```

}
?>